# Can't set image in notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-bitmap, android-glide

I'm creating a simple notification with playback buttons for my audio player. But I have trouble setting the bitmap image for `.setLargeIcon()`. I'm trying to set it using glide. The thing is this image changes as user skips to next song, so this is pretty much a dynamic view. The image sometimes appears (for a split second), when I change the song or pause it. I'll be glad if you guys could help me!

Code:

Build notification:

```
    private void buildNotifications(PlaybackStatus playbackStatus){

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        createChannel();
    }



    int notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;//needs to be initialized
    PendingIntent play_pauseAction = null;

    //Build a new notification according to the current state of the MediaPlayer
    if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING) {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
        //create the pause action
        play_pauseAction = playbackAction(1);
    } else if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED) {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
        //create the play action
        play_pauseAction = playbackAction(0);
    }



   final NotificationCompat.Builder notiB = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID);
    notiB.setShowWhen(false);
    notiB.setStyle(new MediaStyle()
            .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
            .setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2));
    notiB.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_song);
    Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(songInfoModelService.getAlbumIDArtwork()).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

            notiB.setLargeIcon(resource);
        }
    });
    notiB.setContentTitle(songInfoModelService.getSongName());
    notiB.setContentText(songInfoModelService.getArtistName());
    notiB.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "previous", playbackAction(3));
    notiB.addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction);
    notiB.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "next", playbackAction(2));

    notification = notiB.build();
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work synchronously .
`Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load()` is an Asynchronous request so it will execute on separate thread regardless of your current thread . So in this case `notiB.setLargeIcon(resource)` never will get called synchronously.

Solution can be Show the notification inside `onResourceReady()`. Once you download the `Bitmap` then build the `Notification` .

Comment: Try this solution if you face any further problem then let me know .

Comment: That worked...thanks!